# Error "'=' : left operand must be l-value" when writing an if-statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm having to make this code to run a dice game, it's my first game program and I've encountered some errors I've never seen before so I've done my best to fix them. So the only errors I have left are these:

```
'=' : left operand must be l-value
```

for the last three if statements. I know that's probably only the beginning of my problems but I'm new to all this so any advice is GREATLY appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>     //Include Header file for time functions
#include <cstdlib>   //Include Header file for random number generators
#include "graph1.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//Variable Declaration
int rv1 = 0;    //Random number for the 1st dice
int rv2 = 0;    //Random number for the 2nd dice
int seed=0;
int wager=0;

//Display graphics
displayGraphics();

cout<<  "Wager";
cin>>wager;



//Initialize random number generator
srand(time(0));

//Generate two random numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive
rv1 = (rand()%6)+1; /* Function rand() generate a random number, 
(rand()%6+1) generate a random number between 1&6 */
rv2 = (rand()%6)+1;

//rv1
if(rv1=1)
{cout<<displayBMP("1.bmp",200,150);}

else 
{   if (rv1=2)
cout<<displayBMP("2.bmp",200,150);}

if (rv1=3)
{cout<<displayBMP("3.bmp",200,150);}


if (rv1=4)
{cout<<displayBMP("4.bmp",200,150);}

if (rv1=5)
{cout<<displayBMP("5.bmp",200,150);}

if (rv1=6)
{cout<<displayBMP("6.bmp",200,150);}
//rv2
if(rv2=1)
{cout<<displayBMP("1.bmp",200,250);}

if (rv2=2)
{cout<<displayBMP("2.bmp",200,250);}

if (rv2=3)
{cout<<displayBMP("3.bmp",200,250);}

if (rv2=4)
{cout<<displayBMP("4.bmp",200,250);}

if (rv2=5)
{cout<<displayBMP("5.bmp",200,250);}

if (rv2=6)
{cout<<displayBMP("6.bmp",200,250);}


if (wager<5)
{
    cout<<displayBMP("smiley.bmp",250,100);
    gout<<setPos(150,280)<<"Your wager of"<<wager<<"is less than required $5/";
    gout<<setPos(150,295)<<"Please re-run program and enter larger amount!/n";
    return-1;
}
    if (((rv1+rv2)%2)=0)
    {   gout<<setPos(200,280)<<"Dice total"<<(rv1+rv2)<<endg;
        cout<<"You win $2 extra for even roll!/n";
        cout<<"Your winnings:$2+Original Wager:$"<<wager<<"=$"<<wager+2<<endg;
}

    if(rv1+rv2=7)
    {gout<<setPos(200,280)<<"Dice total"<<(rv1+rv2)<<endg;
        cout<<"Youre lucky today!/n";
        cout<<"You double your wager/n";
        cout<<"Your winnings:$10+Original Wager=$"<<wager<<"=$"<<wager*2<<endg;
}
    if(((rv1+rv2)%2)=1)
    {gout<<setPos(200,280)<<"Dice total"<<(rv1+rv2)<<endg;
        cout<<"You lose $2 for odd roll!/n";
        cout<<"Original Wager:$"<<wager<<"Losses:$2=$"<<wager-2<<endg;
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Creris what about jumping in and edit? At your rep stage, you'll even earn additional rep for fixing such.

Comment: I suppose I could. And meh rep is rep, a number next to name

Comment: @Creris Well, being constructive also is an attitude or not. Shut up otherwise please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is used for variable assignment in C++.  You need to use `==` for comparison tests:

```
if (((rv1+rv2)%2)==0)
```

Note too that if-statement conditions written like this:

```
if(rv1=1)
```

will always evaluate to true because `rv1=1` returns the result of the assignment which is `1`.  This is why some C++ programmers write conditions like this:

```
if(1==rv1)
```

which prevents you from accidentally forgetting the second `=` because:

```
if(1=rv1)
```

is a compile-time error.  Of course, writing conditions like this is primarily a matter of style.  I personally do not use this method because it doesn't read very well in my opinion.

Comment: I knew it was probably something obvious that I should have known!It runs now but I have ALOT to fix, thanks so much :)

Comment: If they used proper compilers with full warnings (and acted on them), they wouldn't need to warp their minds using yoda-conditions.

Comment: @TiffanyElizabethBeckham But please don't just blindly write `1==rv1`. This is called Yoda-conditions (you can google that) and it makes the code harder to read and maintain and a good compiler will warn about `rv1=1` anyways.

Comment: Note that I was not _endorsing_ yoda conditions, just merely pointing out that they are how some C++ programmers avoid this problem.  Like I said, it is a matter of style and is therefore the OP's decision to use them or not (just for the record, I too avoid yoda conditions because they do not read well in my opinion :).

Comment: I understand, its a very useful tip and I understand why it would fix these types of accidents. Thanks so much for explaining it the way you did @iCodez, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assignment operator `=` everywhere in the if statements instead of the comparison operator `==` starting from here

```
if(rv1=1)
{cout<<displayBMP("1.bmp",200,150);}
```

There must be

```
if(rv1 == 1)
{cout<<displayBMP("1.bmp",200,150);}
```

and so on.
.